# How to set image height match parent and width the same as height?

Tags: css, react-native

I have the following code:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Image
              source={require('../assets/profile.png')}
              style={{
                width: 80,
                height: 80,
              }}
            />
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
              <Input placeholder="Name" />
              <Input placeholder="Surname" />
            </View>
          </View>
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

But the problem is that width and height of image are hardcoded values. That's why I want to ask if there any way to set image height the same as height of parent view and then set width the same as height? I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

**UPD**

Here's the whole code of screen:

```
const Profile = () => {
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.screenContainer}>
        <View style={styles.inputsContainer}>
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Image
              source={require('../assets/profile.png')}
              style={styles.avatar}
            />
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
              <Input placeholder="Name" />
              <Input placeholder="Surname" />
            </View>
          </View>

          <Text style={styles.inputDescription}>
            Enter your name and upload profile photo
          </Text>

          <View style={styles.inputBlock}>
            <Input placeholder="Phone number" keyboardType="phone-pad" />
            <Text style={styles.inputDescription}>
              Update your phone number
            </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.inputBlock}>
            <Input
              placeholder="Email"
              keyboardType="email-address"
              style={styles.inputBlock}
            />
            <Text style={styles.inputDescription}>Update your email</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View>
          <ButtonSubmit style={styles.updateButton} title="Update" />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screenContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  inputsContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginVertical: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
  },
  inputDescription: {
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    color: 'grey',
  },
  inputBlock: {
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  avatar: {
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
  },
  updateButton: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 60,
  },
});
```

Comment: @Lukas attached code of screen

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `flex: 1` at the `<Image>` component too. In theory, both `<Image>` and `<View>` will have the same height. Then, you just need to adjust `<Image>` width either with `width` or `flex-basis`.

If that doesn't work, please provide a codesandbox like example

Comment: But view with inputs also has flex 1. As I understand it will divide my screen on 2 equal half, won't it?

Comment: Yes @SergeiMikhailovskii. But using `flex-basis` you will control their width and they will no longer be split in equal halves